# In Edit Text auto show previously added E-mail list

Tags: android, email, text, edit, show

I want to show email list when anyone select email address field. I want to design Login Activity, Where When anyone select the username or Email address field , there show email address which i added earlier. How can i do this please help me.

Comment: Save entered emails locally in preference and use AutocompleteTextView to show them

Comment: Just google "autocompletetextview". There are thousands of examples.

Comment: Hi Abir. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions that ask members to code a solution for you are not permitted. Please think of Stack Overflow as a code correction service, not a code writing service. You should have attached a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]) containing the elements of the solution that you were able to implement. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your edit text xml this line.

```
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
```